# Can't log into Minecraft or Mojang

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to use a modpack and used my account. I was asked to login to mojang, so I did. But it said it was incorrect. I reset my password and it still doesn't work. I can't log into `minecraft.net` or the vanilla launcher. My firewall does not block java and I have an English keyboard.

Comment: That's a trouble that we can't solve. You must contact with Mojang Support and then tell your problem, sure they can solve it.

Comment: Are you logging in with your username or your email?

Comment: He's is most likely logging in with his username

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for Mojang support. The forums likely can't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

With minecraft it is now essential to login with your EMAIL  instead of your username, that seems to be where a lot of people fail at logging in